# How to convert SQL Server 2016 GETDATE() function output to MMM dd, yyyy?

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2016

I am writing a stored procedure where I am getting today's date using `GETDATE()` and populating the output in a report, where the date format should be like **Jan 19,2020** but I am getting the output like **2020-01-19**. could someone help me here. I tried many ways but couldn't help.

I have written this code:

```
  DECLARE @v_current_date date;

  SELECT @v_current_date = CONVERT(varchar, GETDATE(), 107);
```

Another one, where I am fetching the date from table where the data is stored as `yyyy-MM-dd` and I want to convert it into like **Jan 19,2020**

```
DECLARE @v_updated_date varchar(1000);

SELECT @v_updated_date = last_updated_date 
FROM us_year_expenditure
WHERE tax_id = @v_each_tax_id
```

Can someone help me out here? Thank you.

Comment: What reporting tool are you using? Most can do the conversion within the report.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you check the [official MS documentation on `CONVERT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), you'll quickly see that there's no predefined style that matches your requirements.

So the only option left is to use the `FORMAT` function (and I'd **also** recommend to use `SYSDATETIME()` instead of `GETDATE()`):

```
DECLARE @v_current_date DATE = SYSDATETIME();

SELECT FORMAT(@v_current_date, 'MMM dd, yyyy');
```

Comment: Thank you marc_s. I was missing this FORMAT() method